# Polymorphic Relation: Assigning parent class and getting collection of children

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm currently fighting with polymorphic relations. What I want to archive is multiple types of attachable objects (video, photo, ...) which I can attach to multiple other objects (event, post) like this:
[image: Relation]
I want to be able to attach photos and videos to a post or a event and then receive a collection of photos and videos with: $post->attachments()

The attachments should be stored in a table like this:

```
attachable_type |   attachable_id   |   attachment_type |   attachment_id
=============================================================================
Post            |   1               |   Photo           |   1
Post            |   1               |   Photo           |   2
Post            |   2               |   Video           |   1
Event           |   1               |   Photo           |   3
Event           |   1               |   Video           |   2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? It's not the first time I've wanted to do something similar and there doesn't appear to be a documented solution anywhere.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But I'm still curious. I read about a workaround which was filtering for the type value. I think it was implemented inside Attachment and was filtering once for Photo and once for Video and returned the combined collection. Not sure how it exactly was working. I didn't bookmark it.

If the child classes have the same fields as the parent class Single Inheritance Tables may be interesting for you: http://www.snooptank.com/single-table-inheritance-with-eloquent-laravel-4/

Comment: I just found this, which hints a solution to one level inheritance with multiple tables: https://laravel.io/forum/05-26-2014-multiple-table-inheritance?page=1